# Writing the huffman tree to file after compression

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I'm trying to write a Huffman tree to the compressed file after all the actual compressed file data has been inserted. But , i just realized a bit of a problem , suppose I decide that once all my actual data has been written to file , I will put in 2 linefeed characters and then write the tree.
That means , when I read stuff back, those two linefeeds (or any character really) are my delimiters. The problem is , that its entirely possible that the actual data also has 2 linefeeds one after the other, in such a scenario, my delimiter check would fail. 
I've taken the example of two linefeeds here , but the same is true for any character string, I could subvert the problem by maybe taking a longer string as the delimiter , but that would have two undersirable effects:
1. There is still a remote chance that the long string is by some coincidence present in the compressed data.
2. Un-necessarily bloating a file which needs to be compressed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to separate the compressed data from the tree data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, write the size of the tree in bytes. Then, write the tree itself, and then the contents itself.

When reading, first read the size, then the tree (now you know how many characters to read), and then the contents.

The size can be written as a string, ending with a line feed - this way, you know that the first number and line feeds belong to the size of the tree.

Comment: That's what I thought of doing initially, but the problem is that the tree can be huge ! So I'll have to write an Integer , that's 4 bytes right there ! 
And If I write it as a character string then I use one byte for each integer that i put in there. Not very efficient for a program that's trying to compress stuff by saving 2 or 3 bits at a time.

Comment: How big do you expect a tree to be? Several kilobytes?

Comment: @angryInsomniac It's even worse than that - `size(tree)+size(compressed_data)` could be bigger than `size(original_data)`, under the right conditions. It obviously only makes sense if your alphabet is small and the data is huge (is not uniformly distributed).

If you're interested in the minimal amount of communication bits (when taking the dictionary into account), there's a big theoretical computer-science (open) research field called Communication Complexity :)

Comment: @user1071136 That ... was my concern , but the nice folks over in the C++ lounge convinced me of the fact that for larger trees, the 4 byte overhead wont really be that big of a deal.
Compression on smaller files would still suck though (read , they would actually bloat in some cases)

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the size and len on the first 8 bytes (4 each) and then the data?
Then something like:

```
uint32_t compressed_size;
uint32_t data_len;
char * data;

file.read((char*)compressed_size, 4);
file.read((char*)data_len, 4);
data = new char[data_len];
zip.read(data, data_len);
```

Should work.
You could deflate the data for better compression.